# Changes not reflected in frontend Typo3

Tags: typo3

I am new to Typo3. We have Test and Development Instances(CMS site) build through Typo3. We dont have problem in Development Instance but have in Test instance. The problem is, Whenever we change some content in pages from Backend, that content is not reflected in Frontend until 24hrs. Still now we did not find the solution. Please, if anyone of you know the solution, please share it. Thanks.

Comment: Did you clear caches manually (via 'yellow flash' icon) ?

Comment: Yes, I clear caches manually through "Clear page content cache".

Answer (score 0):

I have TYPO3 version 6.2 and there I have often problem that it is not enough to remove the cache due the backend and I have to remove cache manually.

That means to remove the content of `typo3temp/cache/*`. Then I can see the changes immediately. (I have to do that especially when I am changing translations).

Comment: Thanks tttpapi. We had found the solution. It is due to .htaccess file. We had made some changes in htaccess file. Now changes are reflecting in frontend.

Comment: can you write the changes that you done in .htaccess file